# Different Logins for Same WooCommerce/Wordpress Account?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Do you guys know if there is a plugin where we can have several logins for 1 wordpress/WooCommerce account ?

Say there is a company which have 1 account, but several people with their own username and password can login and buy stuff.

Any leads ?

Comment: For info, this [thead at woothemes](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/4064) is related and may be [this one too](http://chrislema.com/membership-site-with-woocommerce/). Some related plugins are [Groups for Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/groups/), [Groups for WooCommerce](https://www.woothemes.com/products/groups-woocommerce/), [WooCommerce Memberships](https://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-memberships/) and [WooCommerce Subscriptions](https://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/). Most of this plugins are commercial and kind of expensive.

Comment: For cheaper plugins search over [Codecanyon plugins](http://codecanyon.net/category/wordpress/ecommerce/woocommerce) and  for free ones in **Wordpress plugins section**.

Comment: I appreciate the response. Let me look into it, thanks !